# Deployed on cPanel, how to avoid access to my app.js file by writing it after the link?

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I deployed my app on cPanel. However, if you type 'mylink/'+app.js you have access to my app.js file and that goes for all other js files in my backend.

How can I revoke access to those files on cPanel without revoking access to all .js files?

Thanks

I tried going on Hotlink Protection and removing access to .js butt hat simply removed access to all javascript files.